# How to debug third-party Intellij IDEA plugin?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, plugins

So, I am using a plugin from the Intellij IDEA Marketplace and I'd like to modify it to my needs. The plugin is Open Source(Apache License) but I couldn't find its source code on the internet. I know that plugins are located under `Users` directory in Windows, so I could decompile the jar and see the source code. But the problem is that this plugin contains some `dll` files as well.

Is there an easy way to debug the plugin and set breakpoints etc. to see where I will need to modify the code(the other option would be to include the decompiled java source files in a new plugin build but I don't know what to do with the existing `dll` files).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Intellij Idea plugin development requires a project structure and it requires **gradle-intellij-plugin**. If you are able to compile the source code, you have to create gradle project with gradle-intellij-plugin. First of all follow the links to create a small plugin to understand how to create a plugin.

https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system.html

As a sample project, you can refer below the github project.

https://github.com/debjava/ddlab-gitpusher-idea

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've managed to build a plugin myself, but the problem here is that **this** plugin does not work without the .dll files and I don't really know how to include them in the build

Comment: You have to check in the code about how those dlls are getting called, I mean is there any place where there is some sort of system call from Windows.

Comment: gradle-intellij-plugin is not required, legacy plugin project would work just as well.

Comment: I did not know,Thanks Meo Sir for providing this information.